# can i retrieve data from another collection using MongoRepository?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jpa

i have a class called "Invoice" and a MongoRepository
and what i want is to extract from my mongo database all validated invoices (those created in a given time range)
so here is my mongo repository :

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import Invoices.Invoice;


@Repository
public interface InvoiceRepositoryMongo extends MongoRepository<Invoice,Integer>{

        @Query("db.invoices_bis.find({createdAt : {$gte : new ISODate('2013-04-30T17:24:16.000+00:00') , $lte : new ISODate('2013-05-30T17:24:16.000+00:00')}})") 
        List<Document> testrequete(Date start, Date ed);
}
```

dont pay too much attention to the query it is just for testing , but the problem is when i run this , i have this error :
nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property testrequete found for type Invoice!

i think the problem is that the method return a list of  but i'm not sure

thanks !

Answer (score 1):

i think te problem is that your Entity calls Invoice,

```
MongoRepository<Invoice,Integer>
```

so the result should be something like :

```
List<Invoice> testrequete(Date start, Date ed);
```

Comment: yes , but how can i do in order to return List<Document> please ?